# LDA: find percentage / number of documents per topic

Tags: python, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I'm using LDA to find topics in a corpus. Everything works fine (I have the topics). But I would like to have the percentage / number of documents in each topic. It's possible? I looked at scikit-learn and gensim and could not implement anything.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about what you have done so far and just what you mean by the "number of documents in each topic"? Presumably your latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) provided an estimate of the probability distribution of topics within each document, not just the distributions of words among topics. It's unlikely that a document has a single topic, but you might for example choose the topic having the highest probability within each document. Or perhaps you are interested, for each topic, in the documents for which that topic passes a particular probability threshold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The technically correct, but completely useless answers to your questions:*

Number of documents in each topic: the number of documents in your corpus.
Percentage of documents in each topic: 100%

*Why is that?*

LDA generates vector spaces (among many other things it does). Each document gets a probability of belonging to a specific topic *for all topics* and each topic is comprised of *all documents* with each having a topic-specific weight. Even if the probability of a document belonging to a topic is zero, it still gets generated (in practice, such a probability is never zero, just infitesimally small). Similarly, a topic is comprised of all documents, even if the document weight is 0.0000001.

*What I think you want to see*

For gensim (I dont know the scikit code by heart): Have you tried something like gensim's built-in functions 
`show_topics()` (broad overview of selected topics) or 
`print_topics()`(to get a single topic as a string) or
`get_topic_terms()` (to get word-id and probabilities)

They usually return the top 10 most important topics or words by default, but you can of course play with the settings. You can check the documentation of `gensim.models.ldamodel` [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html).

In practice, you might want to use something like this

```py
for id, topic in lda_model.show_topics(num_topics=20,num_words=10):
   print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(id, topic))
```

to get something like

> Topic: 0  Words: 0.013*"change" + 0.012*"company" + 0.011*"dance"...

which you can reformat to your liking.

Some more inspiration can be found [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/topic_methods.ipynb).